# Permanently setting launcher in Nox

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, settings, launcher, home-screen, default-applications

In Nox (3.8.1.1) running Android 4.4.2, I'd like to change the launcher from Nox Launcher to Smart Launcher. I set the default home app through settings, but every time I restart Android in Nox (or sometimes randomly), the setting doesn't stick and it gets switched back to Nox Launcher. Nox Launcher apparently likes to reset the default app to itself on boot. Also I can't uninstall Nox Launcher, nor can I disable it in settings:

[image]

Is there a way to make the home app setting stick?

Comment: You can't *uninstall* Nox Launcher but you may *disable* it in Settings.

Comment: @iBug Good idea, but unfortunately, looks like I can't; see edit.

Comment: You likely have to disable it through ADB, but you'll want to figure out how to get the default launcher configuration to persist prior to doing so.  Here's a great resource on [debloating Nox](https://gist.github.com/Log1x/12d330ef7685d6fbc611d1d57efb5c29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DviS8RQ2mcE) beeshyams posted in [a comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180343/permanently-setting-launcher-in-nox#comment231960_180343). There's actually a much more concise video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YubeZjj_rBE). I've confirmed that it works correctly in Nox 3.8.1.1, so here are the instructions, which basically just involve disabling Nox Launcher by "removing" the app directly:

1. Make sure you have an alternate launcher installed first! I don't know what will happen if you try this without having another launcher installed. You're welcome to find out, but I didn't want to test it.
2. If not already set, enable root mode in Nox (*Settings → General → Root*) (note I mean the actual NoxPlayer settings in the title bar, the little gear, *not* the settings in Android), then restart Nox to apply the change.
3. Open *File Manager* then navigate to the folder */system/app*.
4. Scroll down until you find one named *launcher_1.7.1_en_signed.apk* (version number / language code may be different in older or newer versions of Nox so your filename may vary slightly).
5. Rename it to *launcher_1.7.1_en_signed.apk.bak* (<kbd>Long Press</kbd> *→ Rename*).
6. Now you're ready to go. Go to the Android *Settings → Home* and make sure your launcher is selected there just to be safe, and it should be good.
7. Disable root mode in Nox if you want then restart it.

To restore the Nox Launcher, just undo the filename change in the same way. If you'd rather see this all visually just watch the "concise" video linked above.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shorter way to do it:

1. Enable root and install any launcher you wish.
2. Use this app to uninstall the Nox launcher (show system apps, and allow in settings to uninstall them):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager

And that's it.

Disclosure: I made the app.